# mongodb replica sets and ec2 - what is the host name

Tags: mongodb

I have two instances of ec2 and I want to create replica sets.  My question for the host..is it the dns name?  e.g.

```
rs.add("ec2-50-xx-xxx-xxx.compute-1.amazonaws.com")
```

If not...then what is?

Thanks

Comment: I added the Private IP Address and seemed to work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the DNS name or the private IP address (avoid the public IP). As long as the servers can "see each other" they should be able to work as a replica set.

A third option to consider, that is also useful in the cloud is to modify your `/etc/hosts` file and use then use computer names like `replica1-a` and `replica1-b`. When Amazon eventually makes one of your computer disappear (*and they will*), it's cleaner this way.

A couple of caveats here:

1. If you are planning to use multiple data centers, the private IP will probably not work.
2. A replica set requires at least 3 separate nodes to truly be a "set". With two nodes, you may get replication of data (*i.e.: they will copy each other*), but you will not get automatic fail-over or high availability. **Do not run production data with less than 3 nodes.**